# Impossible do find motherboard drivers to Dell Dimension 3000

Tags: drivers, dell-dimension

I recently formatted and reinstalled XP on my girlfriends computer. I've had this computer since 2001, never formatted it, until now =) Anyway the problem is that I can't find any drivers for the motherboard (integrated audio, video and Ethernet). as i said its an old ass Dell. Cant remember if I got any CDs along with it. Even if i did they're gone a long time ago.

So, I ran CPUZ and got this:

```
--Motherboard--
Dell Computer Corp. Model 0K8980
```

And started googling. But didnt find any drivers. Still cant

So I'm asking for a little help here.

I really need to get the computer going before she wants a new one :D

And yes I have looked on dells homesite, but they don't seem to wanna host drivers for their old stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for drivers for the board, which is a mistake. Dell assumes all their customers are idiots, so they bundle the software by the machine, not the actual hardware. So what you need to do is look up drivers for a Dell Dimension 3000 and it'll give you the software pack. Or you can just click [here](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&os=WW1&osl=en&catid=&impid=&SystemID=DIM_CEL_3000).

Answer (score 5):

A quick Google reveals that model no to be a Dimension 3000

Dell has plenty of drivers for that model:

http://support.euro.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx?c=uk&cs=ukdhs1&l=en&s=dhs&ServiceTag=&SystemID=DIM_CEL_3000&os=WW1&osl=en&catid=&impid=

Even better, look for the Service Tag on the back/bottom and put that in [here](http://support.euro.dell.com/support/downloads/index.aspx?c=uk&cs=ukdhs1&l=en&s=dhs&~ck=GuidedPathHomePage) to get your exact machine's details

Answer (score 0):

Windows Update is sometimes helpful in this regard.

If you can't find drivers, secondhand PCI add-in cards might be a better solution.

The 3COM 3C905 series of cards are good 10/100 cards, can usually be found fairly cheaply, and have drivers for pretty much every operating system that has ever run on an x86 chip.

As for audio...jury's out on what brand, but if you can find something decent the drivers should be built into XP or readily available from the manufacturer.